# Weekly calendar with data from model and pivot table laravel

Tags: laravel, calendar, relationship

I have two models

Episode
*id
name*

```
 public function programmation() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Programmation::class);
    }

    public function channels() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Channel::class, 'programmation', 'episode_id', 'channel_id');
    }
```

Channel
*id
name*

```
public function episodes() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Episode::class, 'programmation', 'channel_id', 'episode_id');
}
```

Programmation (pivot table)
*episode_id
channel_id
date*

My controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $episodes = Episode::with('channels', 'programmation')->get();
        return view('front.programmations.calendrier', compact('episodes'));
    }
```

I would like to have a weekly calendar page with the day of the week, the episode filtered by the channel and the day of course, like that : https://seriesaddict.fr/programmations

Which is the best way to do it ? Get my episodes with the relationships in my controller ? Make a function in my episode model ?

My view for now

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        <ul class="pagination">
            <a href="{{route('programmations.index', Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->subWeek()->format('j/m/Y'))}}"><li class="left-arrow"> </li></a>

          <li><p>Diffusion séries US : <br /><span  class="calendar-week">Semaine du {{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('j/m/Y')}} au {{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('j/m/Y') }} </span></p></li>

          <a href="{{route('programmations.index', Carbon\Carbon::now()->next(Carbon\Carbon::MONDAY)->format('j/m/Y'))}}"> <li class="right-arrow"> </li></a>
        </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
```

I don't know neither how to get the current carbon instance to display the right date

Answer (score 0):

I would start of by passing date variables from your controller to your view. So create the desired variables using carbon in your controller and pass these to your  blade using with().

Simple example:

return view('yourview')->with(['episodes' => $episodes, ‘now’ => Carbon::now()]);

Comment: But i think my problem is that the Carbon::now() is not appropriate when i want to change the page to go to the following week for example

Comment: Well you should make the date variables dynamic then. If the dates are changed in your calendar you could make a new request using javascript and update the view accordingly.